# Execution of 2 mysql queries in CodeIgniter issue

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter

I've got a Newroom model:

```
<?php if (!defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
    class Newroom_model extends CI_Model {

        function __construct()
        {
            parent::__construct();
        }

        function get()
        {
            $data=array();

            //First
            $query=$this->db->query("call GetHomeTypes()");
            $res = $query->result_array();
            for($i=0;$i<count($res);$i++)
            {
                $data['home_Types'][$i]['Type_ID']=$res[$i]['TypeID'];
                $data['home_Types'][$i]['Type_Name']=$res[$i]['TypeName'];
            }
            //Second
            $query2=$this->db->query("call GetRoomTypes()");
            $res1 = $query2->result_array();
            for($i=0;$i<count($res1);$i++)
            {
                $data['room_Types'][$i]['Type_ID']=$res1[$i]['TypeID'];
                $data['room_Types'][$i]['Type_Name']=$res1[$i]['TypeName'];
            }

            // print_r($data);
            return $data; 
        } 
    }
?>
```

If i'm executing only 1 query in the model - all works fine, but 2 returns nothing.
Can't figure out what's the problem here.

**UPD** I've found that if i use simple query(not procedure) in first part, all is working fine

```
$query=$this->db->query("SELECT TypeID,TypeName
 FROM home_Types;");
    $res = $query->result_array();
     for($i=0;$i<count($res);$i++) {
     $data['home_Types'][$i]['Type_ID']=$res[$i]['TypeID'];
     $data['home_Types'][$i]['Type_Name']=$res[$i]['TypeName'];
```

But i need to use 2 procedures and to find out why it's working so.

Comment: what is your db driver? Check `$db['default']['dbdriver']` in `application/config/database.php`. If it is mysql, just change it to `mysqli`.

Comment: Changed to mysqli, not helping

Comment: did you debug your query? $this->db->last_query()?

Comment: It's returning nothing for second query. But each query alone is working fine, just not together. Getting this error "Fatal error: Call to a member function result_array() on a non-object in"

Comment: check this forum http://ellislab.com/forums/viewthread/71141/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To run more than one procedures in a single page, 1st you need to change $db['default']['dbdriver'] = 'mysql'; to $db['default']['dbdriver'] = 'mysqli'; in config/database.php. Then you need to add this piece of code to mysqli_result.php located in system\database\drivers\mysqli

```
 function next_result(){
    if (is_object($this->conn_id)){
      return mysqli_next_result($this->conn_id);
    }
  }
```

Then when you call the function to for procedure call like this

```
public function SP1($data=array()){
        $stored_procedure= " CALL GetHomeTypes(?,?) ";
        $query=$this->db->query($stored_procedure,$data);
        $result=array();
        foreach ($query->result() as $rows){
            $result[]=$rows;
        }
        $query->next_result();
        $query->free_result();
        return $result;
    }
```

the ? will be replaced by values if parameters are passed as data array

Answer (score 0):

use `$this->db->call_function('nameOfProcedure');` for more info visit this. 
http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/call_function.html